# Chrome extension - persisting HTML injected in popup using data send in message from background

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension ( page action) and is facing a particular issue.

Here is my extension flow. Broadly the extension will look for data in the current tab and show relevant content in popup based on that.

**content.js**

It runs on specific urls ( as defined in `matches` array) and turn on the page action extension by sending a message to `background.js` to show the extension. It is also setup to send messages with data from the current tab to `background.js`

**background.js**

As mentioned above, on receiving specific data from `content.js`, `background.js` will call a backend api to fetch relevant data. Subsequently this data is send in a message which the `popup.js` is expected to display.

**popup.js**

This is setup to listen to event from background and use the data send in message to inject one or more `<li>` items to a `<ul>` element defined in `popup.html` using `jQuery`.

The challenge I'm facing is that when I click the popup, I can't see the inserted list item. However on keeping the pop-up open after clicking it ( after page load) and on subsequently reloading the page, I could see the list item inserted. My requirement is to have the popup page show the list item on message from background and persist it. I should be able to see it when the user clicks the extension icon to open pop-up.

What I'm not doing correctly ?

Comment: Popup window (and its scripts) only exist when open. If you send a message from background script to popup when this latter is not open, it will not work. Use `chrome.storage.local` to store the relevant data in background script and read it from popup script.

Comment: that's good info - could you please add a link ?

Comment: also, in the context of the workflow discussed above , would there be events available to check changes to `chrome.storage.local` so as to use to trigger changes in what  `popup` displays

Comment: [Chrome extension's overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), [chrome storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). In this latter link you can check `chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener` to listen for changes in the storage.